# How to throw observable error in .map for a http status 200 response in Angular 4

Tags: angular, observable

In my Angular 4 app, I call a server's login api with http post.  The server always responds with a stauts 200 whether or not the login was successful.  I want to throw an error based on the server response data.

```
export class AuthenticationService {
...
login(username: string, password: string): Observable<any> {
    let body = `method=login&username=${username}&password=${password}`;

    return this.http.post('http://localhost/rest.php', body)
        .map((response: Response) => {
            let responsedata = response.json();
            if (responsedata && responsedata.success == 1) {
                localStorage.setItem('loggedin',1);
            } else {
                // Not logged in successfully
                Observable.throw(new Error('Not logged in'));
            }

        });
}
```

And my code calling login()

```
trytologin() {
    this.loading = true;
    this.authenticationService.login(this.model.username, this.model.password)
        .subscribe(
            data => {
                // Always returns here regarless of result of login
                this.router.navigate([this.returnUrl]);
            },
            error => {
                // ONLY returns here on a NON-server 200 status
                this.alertService.error(error);
                this.loading = false;
            });
}
```

I think I could intercept the response and change the headers by using `HttpInterceptor`, however this seems like overkill.  Is there another way to get the `subscribe` error to trigger from a 200 status response?

---

**EDIT**

I tried implementing a `HttpInterceptor` without success.

```
import {HttpClient, HttpHeaders} from '@angular/common/http';
import {HttpEvent, HttpHandler, HttpInterceptor, HttpRequest, HttpResponse,HttpHeaderResponse, HttpErrorResponse} from '@angular/common/http';
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/of';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()
export class LoginInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

constructor() {}

intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    // Need to .map so we can go through each event looking for the HttpResponse
    // Can't use .do() as it doesn't update per the docs
    return next.handle(req).map(event => {
        if (event instanceof HttpResponse) {

            let e2 = new HttpErrorResponse({status: 405, statusText: 'Auth error'});
            // return Observable(e2);   // Cannot return as HttpErrorResponse is NOT part of HttpEvent<any>
            Observable.throw(e2);  // <-- Still triggers the success in .subscribe().  Does NOT trigger the .subscribe() error
            event = event.clone({status: 405, statusText: 'Auth error'});  // <-- change the event status.  Can't return HttpErrorResponse as
        }

        return event;
    });

}
}
```

The `.subscribe()` success is always called.

---

**I was incorrect.  :-/**
<strike>**EDIT #2**</strike>

After LOTS of digging, I now know why my code was failing.  But I still don't have a solution!!

The `HttpInterceptor` is the way to go.....*but* the Observer.throw() will only work ***only if the `HttpClient.post()` is on the same domain!!***  The subscribe() error is called if I post() to localhost.  If I call a post() to another domain, it fails to call the subscribe() error.  I put a `console.log()` immediately after the `Observer.throw()`.  There is log output if I have a different domain.  There is **no** log output if the domain is the same.    I don't know if this is a CORS issue as I have control over the server output and have included a `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` header item.

Is this possibly a bug in the `HttpClient` and/or `HttpInterceptor`???  Or maybe a problem with rxjs??

---

Edit #3

If I simply return an `Observable.throw()` in the `intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>>` block my error code gets triggered.  This however will trigger on the http request only. I need to process and throw an error on the **http response**. In order to do this I need to use `return next.handle(req).map()` to look for each `HttpResponse` event.

If I try and execute an `Observer.throw()` inside the `map()` it *does NOT* trigger my error code and is not caught anywhere.  The line after the `Observer.throw()` is executed.

I can't `return Observer.throw()` from the `map()` as it is the incorrect return type.

However, calling a plain javascript `throw()` inside of the `map()` will trigger my error code.

I'm not sure if a plain `throw()` is best practice or if I should be doing something else.

Comment: You can intercept the response from the server and then make an error http response using HttpErrorResponse (I believe you are using HttpClient, not http) and just return that object. Something like this return new HttpErrorResponse({status:401, statusText:"Error of auth"}), let me write complete flow in answer.

Answer (score 3):

You will have to import proper libraries and methods of Observable to get this code working like

```
import { HttpInterceptor, HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';

import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/Observable/of';
```

You can intercept the response and from that response you can take a decision,

```
export class YourInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor{
    intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>>{
              //check your conditions if fall true send this response as given //below
                return Observable.throw(new HttpErrorResponse({status:401, statusText:"Error of auth"}));
        }
}
```

Find the screenshot of a sample code that I tried today,
[image: Component code where service is being called]

[image: Browser console.log output]

Comment: Observable.of(new HttpErrorResponse) cannot be used as HttpErrorResponse is NOT part of HttpEvent<any>.  See the edit in my original post.

Comment: just return return Observable.throw(new HttpErrorResponse({status:401, statusText:"fail response"}));

Comment: just return return Observable.throw(new HttpErrorResponse({status:401, statusText:"fail response"})); However I am not really sure if this is a right way but post this change you will be able to see your error specific code being triggered.

Comment: I have tried that from different servers, let me know if you want me to upload the codes in the git hub or send it to you on your email. My Server runs on 8080 and my client is on 4200 still I am able to intercept and receive the response as required.

Comment: I may have _finally_ narrowed down the issue.  If I simply return a `Observable.throw()` like you have it works, however this will trigger on the http _request_ only.  I want to process the http _response_.  In order to do this I use `return next.handle(req).map()` to look for each `HttpResponse` event.  If I try and execute an `Observer.throw()` inside the `map()` it _does_ nothing.  However, I can issue a plain javascript `throw()` inside of the map() and it works.  I'm not sure if a plain `throw()` is best practice or if I should be doing something else.

Comment: In addition to my previous comment, I can't return `Observer.throw()` from the `map()` as it is the incorrect return type.

Comment: Hey @mminnie you ever achieve your goal without having to use a JavaScript throw. I am in the exact same boat. The only way I can think to get access to the response is using the map operator. And for the reasons you explained I can't return throwError(rxjs 6) within it

Comment: @ErikR  I updated the code to Angular 6, but just reviewed...and there is still the javascript throw.   :-/